# Spring Boot custom endpoint health check

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, health-check

I'd like to create a custom endpoint which gives out some customized info. I know that there are two ways to achieve that: HealthIndicator and @Endpoint.
But I'd like to put my endpoint under another path instead of default /health/xxx, moreover, the original health info which returned from default /health endpoint much be included in my custom endpoint as well. What should I do on this special case? Appreciate it.

Comment: Why not use `@RestController` to implement your own endpoint? The custom data retrieval you need will come from the `HealthIndicator` interface implementation.

Comment: The  /actuator/ endpoint should be there once included, or you just want to redirect /actuator/health to /health?

Comment: @Ferimi-4 Thanks. You mean I hit /actuator/health and retrieve its response manually?

Comment: @BookOfZeus Thanks. I mean I'd like create a new endpoint like /actuator/myCustomHealth instead of putting it directly under the default /health path like /actuator/health/myCustomHealth. But I also need to include all data which returned from default /actuator/health in my new endpoint

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=how+to+create+custom+actuator+endpoint&ia=web

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the url path in the `application.properties`.

Once, I needed to have the health endpoint at `localhost:8080/rest/status` instead of `localhost:8080/actuator/health`.

In order to to this, I added these two settings in the `application.properties` files which did the trick for me.

```
# Change actuator -> rest
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/rest/
# Change health -> status
management.endpoints.web.path-mapping.health=status
```